# How to install all the boost development libraries?

Tags: command-line, libraries

I am having trouble installing boost library completely it fails/skips several things that seem to be key for me to continue on to compiling a program with it.  Here is what I get when I install boost,

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o
libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp:20:56: fatal error: bzlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o" "libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.50.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi>bzip2.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.50.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.50.0...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_iostreams.so for lack of <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.50.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi/bzip2.o
libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp:20:56: fatal error: bzlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi/bzip2.o" "libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi/bzip2.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi>bzip2.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi>bzip2.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_iostreams.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.6/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
```

Ive tried re-installing zlib, and other archive tools like bzip2 but no luck.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Package `libboost-all-dev` installs all the development libraries. Excerpt of the package description:

> This metapackage provides the complete Boost development environment, including all separately-packaged libraries.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

If it fails to locate the package, make sure the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/65926) is enabled.

Headers are located in `/usr/include/boost` and libraries in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`.

Comment: Ah that's it, couldn't remember for name for that package. :)

Comment: really? 

 sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libboost-all-dev

Comment: I actually asked it as my own question and after enabling universe and doing apt-get update it re-appeared. Perhaps you would like to add those to your answer. (Not obvious to everyone... And nothing wrong with stating things that might be obvious to many if it is one of the steps)

Comment: where these files are located

Answer (score 37):

Not specific to Boost, but to get the header files (e.g.: bzlib.h) for a library, you need to install the `dev` packages for it:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Generally, to find in what package(s) a file is contained, use `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search bzlib.h
```

I think there's a meta package for boost libraries though, although I don't remember the name for it.