# problem install in boost lib

Tags: 13.04, libraries

From [how to install boost lib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168053/how-to-install-all-the-boost-development-libraries), I followed the solution but I was met with the following message:

To add more information, I was trying to install the libs due to this thread I posted:
[python keplerian toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476986/pykep-python-keplerian-toolbox)

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-chrono-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-parallel-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-locale-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-math-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-program-options-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-random-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-serialization-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-signals-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-test-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-timer-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this?

```
ii  libboost-atomic1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        atomic data types, operations, and memory ordering constraints
ii  libboost-atomic1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        atomic data types, operations, and memory ordering constraints
ii  libboost-chrono1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
ii  libboost-chrono1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
ii  libboost-context1.53-dev                  1.53.0-3                               amd64        provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread
ii  libboost-context1.53.0                    1.53.0-3                               amd64        provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread
ii  libboost-date-time1.49.0                  1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1                      amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
ii  libboost-date-time1.53-dev                1.53.0-3                               amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
ii  libboost-date-time1.53.0                  1.53.0-3                               amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
ii  libboost-exception1.53-dev                1.53.0-3                               amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
ii  libboost-filesystem1.53-dev               1.53.0-3                               amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
ii  libboost-filesystem1.53.0                 1.53.0-3                               amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
ii  libboost-graph-parallel1.53-dev           1.53.0-3                               amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
ii  libboost-graph-parallel1.53.0             1.53.0-3                               amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
ii  libboost-graph1.53-dev                    1.53.0-3                               amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
ii  libboost-graph1.53.0                      1.53.0-3                               amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
ii  libboost-iostreams1.49.0                  1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1                      amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library
ii  libboost-iostreams1.53-dev                1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library development files
ii  libboost-iostreams1.53.0                  1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library
ii  libboost-locale1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ facilities for localization
ii  libboost-locale1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ facilities for localization
ii  libboost-math1.53-dev                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Math Library development files
ii  libboost-math1.53.0                       1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Math Library
ii  libboost-mpi-python1.53-dev               1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
ii  libboost-mpi-python1.53.0                 1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
ii  libboost-mpi1.53-dev                      1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
ii  libboost-mpi1.53.0                        1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
ii  libboost-program-options1.53-dev          1.53.0-3                               amd64        program options library for C++
ii  libboost-program-options1.53.0            1.53.0-3                               amd64        program options library for C++
ii  libboost-python1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Python Library development files
ii  libboost-python1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost.Python Library
ii  libboost-random1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost Random Number Library
ii  libboost-random1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost Random Number Library
ii  libboost-regex1.53-dev                    1.53.0-3                               amd64        regular expression library for C++
ii  libboost-regex1.53.0                      1.53.0-3                               amd64        regular expression library for C++
ii  libboost-serialization1.53-dev            1.53.0-3                               amd64        serialization library for C++
ii  libboost-serialization1.53.0              1.53.0-3                               amd64        serialization library for C++
ii  libboost-signals1.53-dev                  1.53.0-3                               amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++
ii  libboost-signals1.53.0                    1.53.0-3                               amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++
ii  libboost-system1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
ii  libboost-system1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
ii  libboost-test1.53-dev                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        components for writing and executing test suites
ii  libboost-test1.53.0                       1.53.0-3                               amd64        components for writing and executing test suites
ii  libboost-thread1.53-dev                   1.53.0-3                               amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
ii  libboost-thread1.53.0                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
ii  libboost-timer1.53-dev                    1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
ii  libboost-timer1.53.0                      1.53.0-3                               amd64        C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
ii  libboost-wave1.53-dev                     1.53.0-3                               amd64        C99/C++ preprocessor library
ii  libboost-wave1.53.0                       1.53.0-3                               amd64        C99/C++ preprocessor library
ii  libboost1.53-all-dev                      1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development files (ALL)
ii  libboost1.53-dev                          1.53.0-3                               amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development files
```

Comment: Can you post (or link if it's very long) the output of `dpkg -l libboost* | grep ^ii`?

Comment: @GerhardBurger posted at the bottom of op

Comment: Thanks, what are you trying to get to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke it seems you have already installed a higher version of boost (1.53), the current version which libboost-all-dev points too is 1.49 (see [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-all-dev)). You can't install both, so you will need to remove the newer boost if you want to install the old one.

Comment: did you see the part I added from stackoverflow?

Comment: Oh yes, fortunately the error is not related to boost, I posted a possible solution to your question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unpacking binaries into your system it will be faster for you to just uninstall and install packages again.

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove libboost-all-dev
```

Then install it again with

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Lastly you can clean up with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```